# palavras chaves no site no wordpress, como colocar?

Tags: wordpress

Eu tenho um site feito no wordpress, tranquilo. As postagens e páginas estão com palavras chaves, mas como colocar na página principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instale o plugin "Header and Footer Scripts" e depois vá em "Configurações -> Header and Footer Scripts" e no campo header inclua como neste link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress#Putting_Meta_Tags_Back_In

Seria algo como:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="stories, tales, harriet, smith, harriet smith, storytelling, veterinarian, vets, animal doctor, bravery, brave, courage, life, lives, death, dying, pets, human, companionship, dog, cat, birds, ferrets, pets, pet, birth, puppies" />
```